# Altium: Using Find similar object to change all designator fonts at once

Tags: schematics, altium

I am trying to use Find similar object in Altium designer to change all designator font in my schematic at once. First I Right-click on any designator on the schematic and select Find similar object and Ok. this makes all designators in the sheet to be highlighted. Sch inspector is opened and I select FontId to change the required font. Later I expect that all designator fonts will immediately be changed but actually nothing is happened, Why?!

Comment: If I try that then it is not _FontId_ that I change but just _Font_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because you must Enable "Select Matching" in Find similar Objects. Then press OK and continue to change FontID. That should work!

Comment: Woow! it works well now..